# I have captured one response(text format) in one String. Now I have write in CSV file

Tags: java, csv, file-io

String response ="TITLE,KIND,STATUS,END TIME,CREATION TIME,PATH,OWNER,CUID,DESCRIPTION,
"Input Controls And Charts","Web Intelligence","Success","Mar 2, 2016 8:42 PM","Mar 2, 2016 8:41 PM","/Web Intelligence Samples/","Administrator","AXJksbMs6nRIhXRjrPT1E_c","Web Intelligence 4.0 sample Example of detailed report implementing input controls and element links",
"Charting Samples","Web Intelligence","Success","Mar 2, 2016 8:42 PM","Mar 2, 2016 8:41 PM","/Web Intelligence Samples/","Administrator","ARUoTP3ZkKBFtpDRC0.lWYI","",";

I am storing this response in one string and Now I need to write in one csv file how to write it..?

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more specific and provide any code you have already tried. Leaving it like this nobody will probably help you.

Comment: The question you're posing isn't clear at all. What's the CSV format? Also, what have you done so far to solve the problem by yourself?

Comment: You can have a look at libraries such as: `OpenCSV` or `FasterXML`. It will make the job much easier for you.

Comment: Also,  there is a coma in one of your values: "Mar 2, 2016 8:42 PM", that's gonna be a problem because your string is not well formatted.

Comment: Hi All,  Actually what ever I have assigned in response variable that is a response coming from web service .Now I have to write this response into a csv file.